# Haskell Scotty and Elm Http NetworkError

Tags: haskell, httprequest, elm, web-development-server, scotty

I wanted to look into web development with haskell for the back-end and elm for the front-end. So i wrote this two simple "hello world" code code snippets

elm:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Http
import Json.Decode as Decode

main : Program Never Model Msg
main = Html.program
  { view = view
  , update = update
  , init = ("default", Cmd.none)
  , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none }

type alias Model = String

type Msg = Get | Response (Result Http.Error String)

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model = case msg of
  Get -> (model, get)
  Response (Ok s) -> (s, Cmd.none)
  Response (Err e) -> (toString e, Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model = div []
  [button [onClick (Get)] [text "click me"],
   text model]


get : Cmd Msg
get =  let url = "http://localhost:3000/get"
       in Http.send Response (Http.get url Decode.string)
```

haskell/scotty:

```
import Web.Scotty

main = scotty 3000 $ get "/get" $ json ("hello world" :: String)
```

both work perfectly on their own - meaning the elm code can get data from servers like httpbin and the scotty server handles requests i send with a browser or tools like wget/curl etc fine but when i try to use the two together the http.send call in elm returns a network error

i suspected it may be a problem that both servers are hosted on the same computer (wouldn't know why but i wanted to eliminate the possibility) so i hosted the client site on another computer which i know has a working connection to the computer which hosts the spock back-end (works with wget etc) but it still didn't work.

am i missing something obvious, or what is the problem?
thx in advance

Comment: Do you see any errors logged in the browser console? Are you serving the Elm code from the same port (localhost:3000)?

Comment: no its served on a different port but there actually is an error message in the console (didn't even thing about looking there :D)

backup.elm:1 Failed to load http://localhost:3000/get: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: These errors are often due to Cross-Origin Request Sharing (CORS) restrictions. You may need to modify your server to allow cross-origin requests. [Here is an example using `wai-cors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors)

Comment: thx, solved it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is due to Cross-Origin Request Sharing (CORS) restrictions. You can use [wai-cors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors) to set your CORS policy.

Example:

```hs
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    middleware simpleCors
    get "/get" $ json ("hello world" :: String)
```